# Does the vampire skill Poison Talons work when you're not in vampire lord form?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does the [Poison Talons](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Poison_Talons#Vampire_Lord) skill in Skyrim work when you're not in vampire lord form?

Does the skill still work if you're cured of vampirism?

Comment: I don't believe so. Most of the perks found in the creature skill tree only apply to when you are in that form.

Answer (score 2):

No, Poison Talons will only work if you are a vampire. If you're cured of vampirism, it obviously won't work because you won't ever be a vampire.